# Export an object at a given pixel size

Tags: adobe-indesign

We had an artist create a series of vector art icons, and she sent them to me as an imdd file, a single "page" with all of the icons spaced out vertically. I need to export these to our iOS app, and I'm a bit lost how to do this.

I need to export each one at three resolutions, 24x24, 48x48 and 96x96. Can anyone step me through this? I suspect it's trivially easy, but I can't find my way around the menus.

Comment: Most probably, that `.indd` came with some resource files, which have been 'placed' inside it. Try and find those resource files, and open them--they're bound to be `.ai` or `.eps`.

Comment: Nothing that I can see. Are the files bundles? The Finder doesn't offer to open them.

Comment: Hard to say what's the matter, then. It would be possible, but highly unlikely, that she made the art inside of InDesign. I'd say, try and reach her for more info.

Comment: .indd can embed vector art. Honestly, kind of an inconvenient way to send you files. InDesign doesn't really have many options for exporting specific elements at specific sizes. It's essentially the entire page or nothing. You can use `File > Export..` and choose `EPS`. Then open the EPS in Illustrator which provides *much* better sizing and exporting options. You can also copy/paste from Indesign to Illustrator. Or contact the artist as request an Illustrator file rather than an Indesign file.

Comment: Of course, you could create three InDesign documents with the tree page sizes (pixel dimensions) you need, copy/paste the icons into the various Indesign documents, then export the document pages.

Comment: Scott, perhaps you hit on it. Let me check if that's how it's arranged already.